# jQuery Mobile 1.4: Make left sidebar always visible even on right sidebar reveal

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, panel, sidebar

I have 2 sidebars - left and right. I want the left sidebar to be always visible and wrote this to open it on load:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
    $("#left_sidebar").panel("open");
});
```

All is working fine, but when I try to open the right sidebar, JQM hide the left sidebar auto.
Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: you can't have two active panels at the same time. If one is open, the other closes.

Comment: Is there a way(CSS/JS) which I can 'force' it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be achieved by doing the following alteration to the jquery mobile script:
This very one is jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js

Line 12907:

```
    this.document
        // Close the panel if another panel on the page opens
        .on( "panelbeforeopen", function( e ) {
            if ( self._open && e.target !== self.element[ 0 ] ) {
                //self.close();
            }
        })
```

Basically, you remove the close command that is trigged when another panel opens.

Comment: I say you can't, but then again I'm not a hacker :)